# Unable to send string as HTTPContent

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have created an API, which shall have the capability to connect to en external API via POST and with a request body in form of a string.

I am able to connect directly to the API from Postman without trouble.. But it does not work via my own API.

Any ideas?

This is the [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Msw0rkrw).

```
private string EncodeExternalApiLink = "https://blabla.dk";
private string EncodeExternalApiLinkPostFilter = "searchstring/blabla/api/search";

[HttpPost("getdata/filtered")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataFromExternalFiltered([FromBody] string filter)
{
    var filterString = new StringContent(filter);

    EncodeExternalToken token = GetExternalToken().Result;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(EncodeExternalApiLink);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.access_token);

        using (var response = await client.PostAsync(EncodeExternalApiLinkPostFilter, filterString))
        {
            return Json(response);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return Content(content, "application/json");
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to return the response therefore the "return Json(response);" at that weird place :) The response is "false".

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: `return Json(response);` How does this solve the problem ?

Comment: The server returns and "IsSuccessStatusCode" of false.. The only thing, that can be the reason for this, is it recieves a body(Via post) that it doesn't accept. I know that, what it expects to get is a string and that is what i am sending it, in form of a "HTTPContent", right? :)

Comment: `string content` what error are you getting this variable ?

Comment: I am not getting any error.. The only problem is that the server respons with false accept, as it did not recieve the body it expected... Is this(The code) the right way to send a string via PostAsync?

Comment: *sigh* what does Fiddler show you?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2): "HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of request in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Salutations. You might need to add a "/" to the end of your base address `EncodeExternalApiLink` or to the beginning of `EncodeExternalApiLinkPostFilter`.

Comment: This is not the error. I can call the API from Postman without any problems